# Are $\mathbb S$ and $\mathbb T$ subspaces of the vector space $\mathbb V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\mathbb{V}$ is the set of all real-valued random variables on a fixed sample space forms a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual binary operation (Addition and Scalar Multiplication).

$\mathbb{S}$ is the set of all discrete random variables belonging to $\mathbb{V}$.

$\mathbb{T}$ is the set of all continuous random variables belonging to $\mathbb{V}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear combinations of discrete random variables assume only countably many values so the first set is  subspace.

The second set is not a subspace: If $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$ then $X,Y \in \mathbb T$ but $X+Y \notin \mathbb T$